# Add and Delete rows in DataGridView when Checkbox is checked and unchecked

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

There are two datagridview GroupGrid and ProductGrid. 
Groupgrid contain 3 columns. 1st is checkbox column. data in GroupGrid is populated when from is loaded and it is stored in gGroupArray. I have to populate the Productgrid when checkbox is checked by comparing the categoryID of gGroupArray and gProductArray and delele rows when unchecked. Data that i have to populate is in array named as gProductArray.

Which events will be used and how this can be done. How to check the condition that checkbox is checked or unchecked. I Tried the following

```
  Private Sub groupGrid_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles GroupGrid.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 And Convert.ToBoolean(GroupGrid(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value) = True Then

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim categoryId As Integer = GroupGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CategoryID").Value()

        If gProductArray.Length < 0 Then Exit Sub

        While i < gProductArray.Length
            If categoryId = gProductArray(i).iCategoryID Then
                ProductGrid.Rows.Add()
                ProductGrid.Rows(i).Cells("ProductGroup").Value() = gProductArray(i).tProductGroup
                ProductGrid.Rows(i).Cells("Product").Value() = gProductArray(i).tProductName

                ProductGrid.Rows(i).Cells("CategoryID").Value() = gProductArray(i).iCategoryID
                ProductGrid.Rows(i).Cells("LicenseProductID").Value() = gProductArray(i).lLicenseProductID
                ProductGrid.Rows(i).Cells("SNRequired").Value() = gProductArray(i).bSNRequired
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CellClick Event` is called every time a cell is clicked (it does not matter if you change the checkbox or not). In any case, this event is called before the value of the cell is changed and thus you get the previous state (`False` in case of checking it). You should better consider the `CellValueChanged Event`.

```
Private Sub GroupGrid_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles GroupGrid.CellValueChanged

    If started AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso GroupGrid(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim isChecked As Boolean = DirectCast(GroupGrid(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value, Boolean)
        If (isChecked) Then
            'Cell is checked
        Else
            'Cell is not checked
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

As you can see, I am including a boolean variable (`started`). It is defined globally and set to true at the end of the `Form Load Event`. The reason for using this flag is that the `CellValueChanged Event` can be called before the `Form Load` actions have been completed what would provoke an error in case of using any code involving to affect the given `DataGridView`. Other thing you have to bear in mind is that the value is not changed (and thus this event is not triggered) after clicking on the checkbox, but after "introducing the given value" (e.g., by clicking on any other cell or by pressing enter). A checkbox-cell behaves as a text-cell does: if you input a string in a text-type cell, the values are not stored automatically (you have to press enter or select a different cell). You might have to come up with some additional approach to avoid this last side effect, for example: `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")` on the `CellClick Event` (to force the value to be stored right after clicking/checking).